# Prototyping Qt/C++ in Python

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I want to write a C++ application with Qt, but build a prototype first using Python and then gradually replace the Python code with C++.

Is this the right approach, and what tools (bindings, binding generators, IDE) should I use?
Ideally, everything should be available in the Ubuntu repositories so I wouldn't have to worry about incompatible or old versions and have everything set up with a simple `aptitude install`.
Is there any comprehensive documentation about this process or do I have to learn every single component, and if yes, which ones?

Right now I have multiple choices to make:
Qt Creator, because of the nice auto completion and Qt integration.
Eclipse, as it offers support for both C++ and Python.
Eric (haven't used it yet)
Vim

PySide as it's working with CMake and Boost.Python, so theoretically it will make replacing python code easier.
PyQt as it's more widely used (more support) and is available as a Debian package.

**Edit**: As I will have to deploy the program to various computers, the C++-solution would require 1-5 files (the program and some library files if I'm linking it statically), using Python I'd have to build PyQt/PySide/SIP/whatever on every platform and explain how to install Python and everything else.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> I want to write a C++ application with Qt, but build a prototype first using Python and then gradually replace the Python code with C++. Is this the right approach?

That depends on your goals.  Having done both, I'd recommend you stay with Python wherever possible and reasonable.  Although it takes a bit of discipline, it's very possible to write extremely large applications in Python.  But, as you find hotspots and things that can be better handled in C++, you can certainly port relevant parts to C++.

> Is there any comprehensive documentation about this process or do I have to learn every single component, and if yes, which ones?

Here's what I'd recommend for the various pieces:

**EDITOR/IDE**: Use any editor/IDE you're comfortable with, but I'd highly recommend one that supports refactoring.  If you're comfortable with Eclipse, use it. If you want to mainly go the C++ route and you're not too familiar with any editors, you might be better off with QtCreator.  [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) is an extremely good Python IDE with support for refactoring, unless you're going to be doing lots of C++, take a look at it.  Even better, its source code is an example of good PyQt usage and practices.

**PROCESS**:

The quick summary:

1. Write your application in Python using [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)
2. When identified as hotspots, convert decoupled Python classes to C++
3. Create bindings for those classes using [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/download)
4. Import the newly defined libraries in Python in place of their Python counterparts
5. Enjoy the speed boost

General details:

Write the application in Python using PyQt.  Be careful to keep a good [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) so that when you need to port pieces to C++ they will be separate from their dependencies.  When you finally need to port something to C++, write it in C++/Qt and then create bindings for it using [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/download).  SIP has a [good reference manual](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/) on the process, and you have all of PyQt as an example.

**DEPLOYMENT**:

*C++* - For many applications the dependencies are sufficiently simple that it's not too difficult to create an installer using a tool like [NullSoft's Installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) or [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

*Python/PyQt* - PyQt applications are a bit more difficult to install because of the dependency on Python and its dependence on the presence of the Qt libraries.  One person documented his efforts on [this post at ARSTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2009/03/how-to-deploying-pyqt-applications-on-windows-and-mac-os-x.ars).  *py2exe* works pretty well on Windows and should work fine.  IME, *freeze.py*, which comes with the Python source, sometimes has problems determining which shared libraries are truly necessary and will sometimes end up creating a binary whose dependencies aren't present. [Py2app can be made to work on Mac OS X](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2009/03/how-to-deploying-pyqt-applications-on-windows-and-mac-os-x.ars/2).

**But worse**, however, is the PyQt/Qt licensing.  If you are developing a commercial application, you need to have a commercial PyQt (and Qt) license and make sure to prevent the users from easily modifying the source or otherwise writing code against the PyQt/Qt API [because of licensing restrictions](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/vendorid/intro).  Because of that, the PyQt author created a tool called [VendorId](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/vendorid/intro) (although it has a Python license). Within VendorId is a tool called [SIB](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/VendorID/vendorid.html#creating-a-signed-interpreter) that can be used to create an executable which depends only on the Python interpreter.  But, if you're going to go this far, you might want to install a custom Python along with your application.

*DISCLAIMER*: I haven't used [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) at all, so I'm not sure how it compares to PyQt. Also, note the following warning on their website:

> PySide is a work in progress and is not yet suited for application development requiring production-level stability.

But, on a good note, they intend, at least for the initial release to "maintain API compatibility with PyQt." So, aside from the C++ bindings, you could easily switch between the two later.

Comment: Good answer!  You might consider a section on py2exe / freeze.py in response to the OP's edit, even though they didn't explicitly ask the question.

Comment: @tgray - thanks for the heads up on the edits.  I've added a Deployment section.

Comment: maybe update the `Pyside is not suited for production-level` part since it has been for a while.

Comment: At this point, I'd consider using PyInstaller over Py2exe or Py2app. I've found PyInstaller to work out-of-the-box for small to medium size apps, and is cross-platform compatible as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just learning Qt and want to leverage the speed of prototyping that Python gives you, then I would recommend you make a sample project using `PyQt`.  As you said, there is a debian package, so you are just a simple `apt-get` away from making your first application.

I personally use `gVim` as my Python/Qt editor, but you can really use any Python-friendly editor without much trouble.  I liked `WingIDE` and they have auto-complete for Qt but once you sip from the vim kool-aid it's hard to switch.

I would say that `PySide` is 95%+ compatible with `PyQt` and the `LPGL` license is nice, but if you are just trying to prototype your first Qt app, then I don't think there is a real reason to use `PySide`.  Although, I do like the `PySide` docs better, you can also just use them and replace all the library references with `PyQt`.

Depending on the complexity of the application you are building, it might be better off to just start from scratch with a C++ version than to try to do a bunch `SIP` refactoring black magic.  Once you have a solid grasp of the Qt framework, you should be able to switch between the C++ and Python bindings pretty effortlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I would draw UI mockups before starting to code prototypes. Here are some benefits:

- Quicker than coding prototypes as there is no programming involved
- Quickly fill widgets, such as tables and trees, with data
- Add descriptions and notes to your screens
- Easily integrate mockups into specification documents without having to capture screens
- Validate UI design concepts before implementing

There are a lot of tools that can help you do that, but if you are going to use Qt, [MockupUI](http://mockupui.com) may be a good choice as it renders Qt widgets with native styles for Windows 7,8 or 10 which makes your mockup look more realistic.